# How do I create a seaborn lineplot with multiple lines showing the distribution of values per category?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have a dataframe of cars from 5 different brands with all models and their technical data.
Simplified it looks like that:

| Brand | Model | Power in HP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VW | Golf 7 | 150 |
| Audi | A4 | 190 |
| Audi | A5 | 190 |
| VW | Passat | 240 |
| VW | Polo | 80 |
| Ford | A4 | 190 |
| KIA | A4 | 190 |
| Audi | Q3 | 150 |
| Audi | S6 | 400 |
| VW | Golf 6 | 140 |
| VW | Golf 5 | 116 |
| ...... |  |  |

How can I create a multi line plot that shows the distribution of HP for each brand? (each brand is a line in the plot)

I tried the function groupby or simply giving the dataframe columns into the lineplot constructor but that didn't work..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuUvR.png)

Comment: also, it is categorical data, so a line plot does not have a meaning.  do you mean a bar chart ?

Comment: Instead of writing *"that didn't work"*, could you show your best-effort code (as text), its result (as image of the plot) and a detailed explanation of what you need to be different?

Comment: @D.L the HP Column is not categorial, that's why I think a line would work there (in summary 4 Lines because of 4 brands)

Comment: @JohanC you're totally right, next time I will do that. Thanks for advice

Comment: @JohanC I don't have the code anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in seaborn.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Load data into a pandas DataFrame
data = {'Brand': ['VW', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'VW', 'VW', 'Ford', 'KIA', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'VW', 'VW'],
        'Model': ['Golf 7', 'A4', 'A5', 'Passat', 'Polo', 'A4', 'A4', 'Q3', 'S6', 'Golf 6', 'Golf 5'],
        'Power in HP': [150, 190, 190, 240, 80, 190, 190, 150, 400, 140, 116]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Use seaborn's "FacetGrid" to create a grid of plots
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Brand", col_wrap=2)

# Map the histogram on the grid
g.map(sns.histplot, "Power in HP", kde=True, bins=10)

plt.xlabel('Power in HP')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

which will plot this:

[image]

but you should note that because the data is spars for `ford` and `kia` (only one point for each), that nothing will show...

Comment: the dataset is bigger, thats just a example dataset with few rows...
Is it possible to remove the bars and draw the lines all in one (line) chart?

Comment: yes it is and, in fact, the data plots will be much better (more coherent) in a bigger dataset.

Comment: do you mean 4 lines in one chart or 4 separate lines (both are definitely possible). it might be worth asking as a new question...

Comment: I used your solution but without kde. I think it's even clearer than multiple lines in one plot